# How do I change a file link when I change the object content

Tags: javascript, html

I am a noob at Javascript, and I am trying to change a file link when I click on an anchor. Maybe I am going about this all wrong, but here it is. I want to change the PDF download link based upon the PDF I am displaying.

I have four links that are calling a file to populate the HTML object. The link I am trying to change is outside the object.

```
<div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodEnvelopes()' id="ww">Heywood White Wove</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodMI()' id="mi">Heywood White Wove MI</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodRemittance()' id="re">Heywood Remittance</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="javascript:heywoodBC()" id="bc">Heywood Booklets &amp; Catalogs</a></div>
```

When I click on those links, I want the following href to change:

```
<span class="download-link">If your browser does not support viewing PDF's, please click<a class="download" href="#" id="pdfLink" download> HERE </a>to download a copy.</span>
```

Here I tried one link in Javascript, but it is not working because I do not know what I am doing.

```
document.getElementById("ww").onclick = function () {
document.getElementById("pdfLink").href = "/products/HeywoodWhiteWove.pdf";
return false;
};
```

Complete HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Heywood Envelopes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/products.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/merchant.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/changeLink.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="include" data-include="/header.html"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu-container">
        <div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodEnvelopes()' id="ww">Heywood White Wove</a></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodMI()' id="mi">Heywood White Wove MI</a></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodRemittance()' id="re">Heywood Remittance</a></div>
        <div class="menu-item"><a href="javascript:heywoodBC()" id="bc">Heywood Booklets &amp; Catalogs</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="object-container">
        <div class="download-link">
            <span class="download-link">If your browser does not support viewing PDF's, please click<a class="download" href="#" id="pdfLink" download> HERE </a>to download a copy.</span>
        </div>
        <object class="pdf" data="/products/HeywoodWhiteWove.pdf" type="application/pdf" id="display" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-include="/footer.html"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/load.js"></script>
<script>include();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code sample does not include an element with the id `#pdfLink`

Comment: It actually does, Christophe; it's inside the 'download-link' span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided should work. There is something else wrong on your page.

```js
document.getElementById("ww").onclick = function () {
document.getElementById("pdfLink").href = "/products/HeywoodWhiteWove.pdf";
return false;
};
```

```html
<div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodEnvelopes()' id="ww">Heywood White Wove</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodMI()' id="mi">Heywood White Wove MI</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href='javascript:heywoodRemittance()' id="re">Heywood Remittance</a></div>
<div class="menu-item"><a href="javascript:heywoodBC()" id="bc">Heywood Booklets &amp; Catalogs</a></div>


<span class="download-link">If your browser does not support viewing PDF's, please click<a class="download" href="#" id="pdfLink" download> HERE </a>to download a copy.</span>
```

Comment: I posted the complete HTML on top.

Comment: Firefox is also throwing this error: 

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: @MichaelTuma I'm guessing this javascript is inside changeLink.js? If so, that's the problem - you're calling it before the element exists. Move that script down below the footer with your jQuery/Bootstrap/etc.

Comment: That was the issue, however it must be conflicting with the other Javascript because now my calls to fill my HTML object are not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space in the string you want to set as href. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: That is a typo, my JS does not have that space.